# How do I install p4v (previously p4merge) as my git difftool on macos catalina 10.15.3

Tags: macos, command-line, homebrew, git

Ive found these instructions for setting up p4merge as my git difftool (I've not been able to test these instructions):

```
brew cask install p4merge
git config --global diff.guitool p4mergetool
git config --global difftool.p4mergetool.cmd \
  "/Applications/p4merge.app/Contents/Resources/launchp4merge \$LOCAL \$REMOTE"
```

I've learnt that p4merge was renamed p4v. So I now have to do:

```
brew cask install p4v
```

but I'm not sure how this impacts the other commands given. Can anyone clarify how to setup p4merge as your difftool when using p4v? thx

Comment: After you install `p4v` how are the installed commands called?

Comment: The name of the tool is not necessarily the name of the command.  For example ImageMagick is the name of the tool, but the commands are `convert`, `identify`, `composite`, etc.  What commands did you have issue with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't impact the commands given.

Just `brew cask install p4v` and all other commands remain the same.